# No funciona mi Sweet Alert en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

espero se encuentren bien.

Tengo el siguiente código:

Aca tengo el href que me enviara al procesar en el caso de que le presione al mensaje 'SI'

```
<?php echo "<a href='eliminarp.php?idprs=".$row['idprs']."&estatus=".$nuevoestatus."' id='txt_test' onclick='return ConfirmDelete()'>Borrar</a>";?>
```

Y este es el mensaje:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ConfirmDelete() {
        
    var respuesta = Swal.fire({
    title: "Confirmar Accion",
    text: "Esta a punto de eliminar un proyecto, quiere continuar?",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#f7505a',
    cancelButtonColor: '#f7505a',
    confirmButtonText: "SI",
    cancelButtonText: "NO"

    })
    
    if (respuesta == true)
        {
            return true;
        }   
    else
        {
            return false;
        }
    
    }
    
    
    
  
</script>
```

El problema es que no va al procesar, al presionar clic en el botón SI solo se cierra el cuadro.

Por favor me podrían indicar que estoy haciendo mal.

Cualquier ayuda me podría ser de gran utilidad.

Actualmente estoy usando la librería de Sweet Alert 2

Muchas gracias.

Comment: es que según entiendo, tu sweet alert no realiza ninguna acción. Simplemente se cerrará cuando le den click. Supongo que quieres que cuando le den se elimine. Eso tendrías que hacer via ajax. Estoy seguro que igual eliminas el producto.

Comment: La observación de @gaidyjg es clave. Que necesitas que haga al apretar Sí?

Comment: Necesito que al apretar SI me envie al enlace que esta en el <a> eliminarp.php

Answer (score 1):

Podrias usar el método then de sweet alert,
en vez de hacer el href con un onclick, puede hacer un onclick y pasarle a tu función los parámetros del href y luego hacer un href desde javascript para ir al link donde eliminar

Una idea de como hacerlo seria:

```
<?php echo "<a id='txt_test' onclick='ConfirmDelete('".$row['idprs']."','".$nuevoestatus."')'>Borrar</a>";?>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.1.7/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function ConfirmDelete(idprs,nuevoestatus){
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Confirmar Accion',
                text: "Esta a punto de eliminar un proyecto, quiere continuar?",
                icon: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Si'
            }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                windows.location.href = 'eliminarp.php?idprs='+ idprs+'&estatus='+nuevoestatus;
            }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Hola José, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Intento hacer el ejercicio pero al presionar clic en el <a> ya no ejecuta nada. se queda alli y tampoco abre el modal. super raro.